Sorry, I didn't mean to spam you
I have a question about my Chinese Language Stack Exchange post: Is there any tool to help learn Chinese with Youtube Chinese songs and Netflix movies?
Hi, My name is Diep, I'm here to contribute to the Chinese Language Stack Exchange. I'm here also to learn from Chinese experts. I read several thoughtful answers and I greatly respect your work. 
I did read through the Help Center to avoid spamming or annoying other users. However, I may misunderstand something and unintentionally violate the group's rules. I just want to make clear that I don't mean to spam the community. 
What I need help is this: I'm a Chinese learner, looking for a tool to learn Chinese via movies & videos. I have come up with an idea of creating a tool to meet my needs, and hopefully other learners as well. I came here to ask if there's any existing tool like that. I haven't got a product relating to Chinese language yet to promote. All I got is just an idea and some first lines of code. Your support may save me from doing a worthless project.
I did talk about my idea in 1 or 2 groups. Nevertheless, I lack ideas from a Chinese expert like some of you in this forum. I hope you may help advise me where I can seek support. 
Again, I'm sorry if I worried you.
